# accessing data from the model using script/console (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, scripting, model, console

I'm looking to write a Ruby script which I can load into the Rails Console which will access data from the models I have created. I created a model called student using the following command and populated it with data:

```
script/generate scaffold student given_name:string middle_name:string family_name:string date_of_birth:date grade_point_average:decimal start_date:date
```

how would I, for instance, get the script to print a list of names of all the students? are there any resources which describe how to do this in detail? I haven't been able to find anything. Thanks!

- Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
students = Student.all
students.each do |student|
  p student.name
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want:

```
Student.all.collect(&:name)
```

- You can find an explanation of the syntax in this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/6-shortcut-blocks-with-symbol-to-proc).